# AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codeaurora.telephony.utils.AsyncResult cannot be cast to org.codeaurora.telephony.utils.AsyncResult

Tags: java, android

In Android 10, Google made all `android.os.* classess` inaccessible for non-system apps by annotating with `UnSupportedAppUsage`.
To workaround this, platform vendors, provided a replica of such classes without annotations.
So, in the application instead of importing `android.os.AsyncResult`, I imported the one from platform vendor. But, its leading to this exception.
Wish to know why such an error when the object being cast and the type to which its cast is the same

Comment: Just don't use `AsyncTask` - problem solved.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, Thanks. Did you mean AsyncResult ? If no, what to use instead of AsyncTask?